# Storing 'formattable' strings in database

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm working on a project where I need to store certain descriptions in a database. These descriptions need to be strings akin to prepared statements in SQL, where I can later 'inject' my own values wherever necessary. The reason is that the data that goes in the fields needs to be generated by the backend on demand (also the descriptions will potentially be localized later on).

Currently I'm simply storing the descriptions in the form of "This is the description for {} and {}" and in the backend I call `.format` on it to pass the generated values. It's probably worth noting that the user can't interact with this procedure, meaning it shouldn't really be a security hole. However, is there a better way of doing this in Django? Or is my design somehow flawed?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to use Jinja templating

Comment: You mean as a model field? I'm not using Django's templating system, but DRF

Comment: Perhaps better `"text {foo} and {bar}".format( **dict)` where dict is `{'foo':'stuff',  'bar':'morestuff'}` which avoids possible positioning errors and integrates very well with JSON.

Comment: Use Django format_html if there's the slightest risk of the parameters containing malicious or even accidental HTML

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the idea of storing it in that form is not that bad then

Comment: I dont think you are preventing from SQL injections atacks using format in a string. the best is to use the parameters argument of you sql cursor and have a proper query, I think this vary on the SQL flavor. Check for example https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders

Comment: Injection isn't really possible because the injected variables aren't  user inputs but generated from an internal function that I control

Comment: The main question is: what are the variables that you want to use to *render* the string, as in if your string contains `'{foo} {bar} {qux}`, where do the `foo`, `bar` and `qux` originate from, are  these the (other) fields of your model object, or something else?

Comment: They are constraints that I store as a JSONField in Django

Comment: @Pol: constraints? You mean a field or something, so it is part of the model, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. They are constraints that the generator functions (the ones that fill the template variables) need to follow.